# Basic threading in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Ive seen some example code that creates a number of threads that looks as follows:

```
var simpleThreads = new[] { 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple)), 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple)), 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple))
        };
```

Logically, is this the same as the following?

```
var ts = new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple);    
var simpleThreads = new[] { 
                new Thread(ts), 
                new Thread(ts), 
                new Thread(ts)
            };
```

I put a stopwatch on both pieces of code and they took roughly the same amount of time, so am wondering why the first block of code is written as so, unless it was to save one line of code.

Comment: They will have the same effect; they are *semantically* equivalent. It helps that delegates are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really take credit for this answer but, to quote Marc Gravell,

> They will have the same effect; they are *semantically* equivalent.
>      It helps that delegates are immutable.

To expand in my own blundering way.

This is not really a question about threading. The `Thread` constructor will work equivalently, if equal `ThreadStart` delegates are passed.

The key "attribute" of the delegate type is its immutability. Once an immutable type has been instantiated it cannot be altered. This is relavent because all the `ThreadStart` delegates in both code samples are constructed with the `ThreadSimple` method group. Therefore, all `Thread` instantiations are passed an equivalent delegate, regardless of the delegates lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the second on is better because you only create one ThreadStart instead of 3 but i don't know if this will give problems because of sharing this object over multiple threads.

Comment: Delegates are immutable; sharing isn't a problem

Answer (score 0):

The two snippets are **not logically equivalent**.
In the first, you have three different objects of type ThreadStart, while in the second you only have one.

Comment: a delegate is immutable and has no properties to change.

Comment: You're right, the example I used is incorrect. But you can't ignore the fact that you're creating three different objects.

Comment: yes, I misread that and edited my comment accordingly; however, the fact remains that your second paragraph is misleading: *it is immutable*: there is nothing to change

Comment: Edited To remove it. Thanks for drawing my attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
var simpleThreads = new[] 
{  new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple)),
 new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple)),
 new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSimple))  };
```

and new Thread(ts) are not the same thing.

In the first code block you have generated three new threadstart object although refering the single delegate but in second which is a better implementation, you have done without creating unnecessary objects and saving the LOC as well.